# Non-compact complex foliation on a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold and let $\mathscr F$ be a foliation on $M$ such that each leaf $ F\in \mathscr F$ is a non-compact complex manifold.

Is it true that a function $f:F\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic iff $f$ is a constant?

Comment: As it stands, you're asking if a function on a *single* leaf (which can be endowed with some complex structure) must be constant if it's holomorphic. Take a foliation where the leaves are diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb C$, and choose a complex structure for one of the leaves. You certainly can take nonconstant holomorphic functions on that particular copy of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thanks Ted! So if we assume that $M$ is homogeneous under a Lie group action and  the leaves are orbits  and all of them are biholomorphic. Does that change anything?